# Package opencv was not found in the pkg-config search path when trying to build docker image

Tags: opencv, docker, ubuntu, environment-variables

I'm trying to build docker image, but I have this

> app/utils
>
> app/vendor/fifo/fifobuffer_v2
>
> parkingDetection/pkgs/utils
>
> app/pkgs/utils
>
> app/vendor/github.com/stratoberry/go-gpsd
>
> parkingDetection/gpsdata
>
> gocv.io/x/gocv app/gpsdata
>
> pkg-config --cflags opencv
>
> Package opencv was not found in the pkg-config search path.
>
> Perhaps you should add the directory containing `opencv.pc'
>
> to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
>
> Package 'opencv', required by 'virtual:world', not found
>
> pkg-config:
>
> exit status 1

```
  apt-file search opencv.pc
```

gives me

> libopencv-dev: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/opencv.pc

```
  echo $PKG_CONFIG_PATH
```

gives me

> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/opencv.pc

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

So, I guess, I just can't build docker image, which uses ppencv without opencv on my pc

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when I was trying to install a deep learning framework and this is how I fixed it:

Add the following to your .bashrc file:

```
PKG_CONFIG_PATH=$PKG_CONFIG_PATH:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig

export PKG_CONFIG_PATH
```

then run the .bashrc file by either

```
source ~/.bashrc

or 

. ~/.bashrc
```

I hope it works for you.